# pytest coverage for class methods

Tags: pytest, coverage.py

I have a class with many methods that I regularly test with a command

> python3 -m pytest --doctest-modules --cov=yarsync --cov-report term-missing yarsync tests

Unfortunately, it outputs missing lines for the whole class (module), like

```
yarsync/yarsync.py     1031    259    75%   60, 69-70, 77, 160-167, ...
```

Is it possible to split output based on class methods? I tried [annotate](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.4/cmd.html#text-annotation-coverage-annotate), but that seems redundant (and already discouraged by developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coverage.py doesn't divide its reports into methods.  You can use the line numbers to find the problem areas in your code.  `coverage html` provides a highlighted HTML report.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer some references, but judging by your profile, you are an expert on coverage, so I trust your opinion here.

Comment: The reference is the coverage.py docs: https://coverage.readthedocs.io .  There is no feature mentioned there that does what you want.

Comment: I think that this reference is too broad. I made a feature request, let us see what they reply. https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1532

Comment: Fun fact: "they" is me!  I don't know what you mean by "too broad": it documents the tool.

Comment: This is a fun fact indeed :) I read your profile here, but didn't see coverage mentioned. But I can see the repo's owner now. Well, I thought about some more specific options. Anyway, many thanks for your work!